# How can I check the build command for my JavafX app in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

Im creating a JavaFX application in IntelliJ IDEA, and I am new to IntelliJ.

I would like to be able to compile my JavaFX application on a Raspberry Pi, but my app is quite complex and relies on 3rd party libraries, etc.

I would like to be able to see what exactly is going on in IntelliJ when I run "Make Project"

**Is there a command line output screen that Im simply missing? I want the exact command that IntelliJ uses to compile the application.**

Essentially, on the Pi, I want to get the code from my repo, run the compilation command and produce an executable JAR on demand.

I have of course read the doco on how to compile a JavaFX application, but if I could see what IntelliJ does, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I haven't found such an option but the process is most likely some sort of flow based on IntelliJ plugins and [the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/compilation-types.html) seems to support this theory.

Perhaps you'd consider using a software management and build tool such as [maven or ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603189/differences-between-ant-and-maven) or something similar. This should give you (almost) unlimited options to configure your desired build sequence and 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: yeah, I figured that might need to be the case. I know that IntelliJ lets you generate ANT files, which I have done, now its a matter of just ensuring that I can run them manually

Comment: If i were you, I'd go with maven as it more flexible and you also get the benefit of its distributed dependency management system. You could also setup a Jenkins server on your PI to make your build procedure even friendlier

Comment: I did find out how to do this, BTW, in the messages log there is an icon which shows raw output, including the command used to generate the build or run the app!

Comment: @Mark Hmm, didn't see that so far. Thanks for sharing