# Where is library option in Netbeans 15 project properties

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, ssms

[image: Can someone tell me where i can find libraries option in project properties]

I have tried tutorial video in youtube but i cant find anything to help me , can someone tell me where i can find this library option ?

Comment: Since you have created a Maven project, there is no _Libraries_ option for your project, as there would be for an Ant project. Instead, dependencies for a Maven project are specified in your project's [pom.xml file](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

Comment: There are many older NetBeans tutorials on the web which assume you are using Ant (and that used to be the default Java project type in older versions of NetBeans). These days, for more recent versions of NetBeans, you choose between Ant, Maven and Gradle, when you create a new Java project. If you have never used Maven, I would [recommend taking a look at it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/603189/12567365).